# Why is ( x & 3 ) identical to ( x mod 4 )?

Tags: math, operators, bitwise-operators

I found some example source code where the author seems to use bitwise `&` operator instead of `%` operator. However when I tried `x & 4` it doesn't produce the same value as `x % 5`.

Comment: In the old days doing the bitwise was much faster than doing the modulo so it was a cool "micro-optimization" for powers of two : )

Comment: @user988052 Still is. 10% faster under .NET (just tested), the code is here http://ideone.com/BLqZP (but note that on ideone the difference is much smaller). Release + Run Without Debugger.

Comment: @user988052: Bitwise and is still faster than any general-purpose `mod` implementation that has to handle *all* numbers. But this optimization is so well-known and simple that many compilers implement it, so yeah. @xanatos: Be sure to let the JIT warm up first when benchmarking.

Comment: @xanatos: when I'm talking about *"much faster"* back in the days I'm talking about the *bitwise* taking one or two CPU cycles and the modulo, using the remainder of a *div* in a register, needing close to CPU 20 cycles if not more.  So when I meant *"much faster"*, I was talking about nearly *an order of magnitude faster* (10x if not much more, depending on the hardware).  I'm not talking about a mere 10% which, as *delnan* pointed out, may be optimized automatically anyway nowadays ; )

Comment: @delnan Wow!! It's true!!! When it's warm!!! **it's warm**!! No, no differences! Tried a cycle of 100 times and looked only at the last benchmark. C# doesn't fully optimize & and %

Comment: Compilers can only do this optimisation for unsigned values, or for signed values that are known to be positive. Which means that sometimes a human can perform this optimisation in a case where the compiler can not (because the human has *a priori* knowledge which the compiler lacks).

Answer (score 17):

This only works for powers of 2.

In general:

```
x MOD 2^n
```

is equivalent to:

```
x AND (2^n - 1)
```

Note also that this may be true only for `x >= 0`, depending on your definition of `MOD` for `x < 0`.

---

To understand *why* this works, consider what MOD really is - it's just the *remainder* after performing integer division. In the case of a division by 2^n, we are effectively just shifting a binary value right by n bits and discarding any low order bits that get shifted out, e.g. for an 8 bit binary number

```
a b c d e f g h
```

if we divide by 4 = 2^2 then we shift right by 2 bits:

```
0 0 a b c d e f
```

The remainder (`g h`) has been thrown away as a result of the integer division.

If we wanted to know the remainder then we could just extract the bits `g h` by applying a mask of `0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1`:

```
    a b c d e f g h
AND 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
  = 0 0 0 0 0 0 g h
```

Note that the has has value 3, which in the general case is just 2^n - 1.

Let's try this with some real numbers. Suppose we want to calculate 42 / 4 and get both the quotient and the remainder:

```
42 = 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

To get the quotient we shift right by 2 bits:

```
  42 / 4 (decimal)
= 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 >> 2
= 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
= 10 (decimal)

  42 MOD 4 (decimal)
= 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 AND 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
= 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
= 2 (decimal)
```

So 42/4 = 10 remainder 2.

Answer (score 4):

The answer quite simple, try to think in binary.

```
0000 = 0 AND 11 = 0000 = 0
0001 = 1 AND 11 = 0001 = 1
0010 = 2 AND 11 = 0010 = 2
0011 = 3 AND 11 = 0011 = 3
0100 = 4 AND 11 = 0000 = 0
0101 = 5 AND 11 = 0001 = 1
0110 = 6 AND 11 = 0010 = 2
0111 = 7 AND 11 = 0011 = 3
```

... and so on.

This have the same result as reminder (% is remainder, formally, not modulus).
It works only with powers of 2 and only for zero and positive numbers.